# Dashed lines in Matlab 3d plot

Tags: matlab, 3d, line

I am trying to make a 3d plot with dots in 3 different planes connected by dashed lines.
The data are in 2 groups:

Group 1 I am trying to connect with black semi-transparent dashed lines - here i am having trouble.

Group 2 I am trying to connect with black semi-transparent dashed lines - works just fine.

In group 1, it seems that matlab draws two lines on top of eachother, a semi-transparent normal line with a dashed non-transparent line on top. The codes for the two lines are identical, only the data and the colors differ.

Here is my entire code:

```
data = xlsread('rdata.xlsx','PCOA','A2:E43');
weight = xlsread('rdata.xlsx','PCOA','A45:C45');

data(:,1)= -data(:,1);

depl0  = data(1:7,[1,2]);   
deol4  = data(8:14,[1,2]);
depl9  = data(15:21,[1,2]);   
undepl0      = data(22:28,[1,2]);
undepl4 = data(29:35,[1,2]);   
undepl9     = data(36:42,[1,2]);

depl0   = [ones(7,1),depl0];
deol4       = [2*ones(7,1),deol4];
depl9   = [3*ones(7,1),depl9];
undepl0       = [ones(7,1),undepl0];
undepl4  = [2*ones(7,1),undepl4];
undepl9      = [3*ones(7,1),undepl9];

hold on
s1 = plot3(depl0(:,1),depl0(:,2),depl0(:,3),'.','MarkerSize',20);
s2 = plot3(undepl0(:,1),undepl0(:,2),undepl0(:,3),'s','MarkerSize',5,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 1/255 127/255],'MarkerFaceColor',[0 1/255 127/255]);
set(s1,'color',[0 0 0]);
set(s2,'color',[0 1/255 127/255]);
l = legend('FoxP3-DTR^+','FoxP3-DTR^-');
set(l,'box','off','Location','NorthOutside','Orientation','horizontal');
s1 = plot3(deol4(:,1),deol4(:,2),deol4(:,3),'.','MarkerSize',20);
s2 = plot3(undepl4(:,1),undepl4(:,2),undepl4(:,3),'s','MarkerSize',5,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 1/255 127/255],'MarkerFaceColor',[0 1/255 127/255]);
set(s1,'color',[0 0 0]);
set(s2,'color',[0 1/255 127/255]);

s1 = plot3(depl9(:,1),depl9(:,2),depl9(:,3),'.','MarkerSize',20);
s2 = plot3(undepl9(:,1),undepl9(:,2),undepl9(:,3),'s','MarkerSize',5,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 1/255 127/255],'MarkerFaceColor',[0 1/255 127/255]);
set(s1,'color',[0 0 0]);
set(s2,'color',[0 1/255 127/255]);

% Line depleted (7 instance)
for i = 1:7
    X = [depl0(i,1), deol4(i,1), depl9(i,1)];
    Y = [depl0(i,2), deol4(i,2), depl9(i,2)];
    Z = [depl0(i,3), deol4(i,3), depl9(i,3)];
    line(X,Y,Z,'color',[0 0 0 0.5],'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','--');
end

% Line undepleted (7 instance)
for i = 1:7
    X = [undepl0(i,1), undepl4(i,1), undepl9(i,1)];
    Y = [undepl0(i,2), undepl4(i,2), undepl9(i,2)];
    Z = [undepl0(i,3), undepl4(i,3), undepl9(i,3)];
    plot3(X,Y,Z,'color',[0 1/255 127/255 0.5],'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','--');
end

% Grid 
for i =1:3
    X = [i,i];
    Y = [0.1,0.1];
    Z = [-0.4,0.4];
    line(X,Y,Z,'color',[87/255 91/255 69/255]);
    Y = [-0.1,-0.1];
    line(X,Y,Z,'color',[87/255 91/255 69/255]);
    Y = [-0.3,-0.3];
    line(X,Y,Z,'color',[87/255 91/255 69/255]);
    Y = [-0.5,-0.5];
    line(X,Y,Z,'color',[87/255 91/255 69/255]);
    Y = [-0.5,0.3];
    Z = [0,0];
    line(X,Y,Z,'color',[87/255 91/255 69/255]);
    Z = [0.4,0.4];
    line(X,Y,Z,'color',[87/255 91/255 69/255]);
    Z = [0.2,0.2];
    line(X,Y,Z,'color',[87/255 91/255 69/255]);
    Z = [-0.2,-0.2];
    line(X,Y,Z,'color',[87/255 91/255 69/255]);
end


% Three planes
syms x y z
ezsurf(sym('1'),y,z,[-0.5 0.3 -0.4 0.4]);
ezsurf(sym('2'),y,z,[-0.5 0.3 -0.4 0.4]);
ezsurf(sym('3'),y,z,[-0.5 0.3 -0.4 0.4]);
shading interp
alpha(0.1)
CM=[143/255,151/255,104/255];
CM=repmat(CM,64,1);
colormap(CM);

ytitle = strcat('PC 1 (',num2str(weight(1)),'%)');
ztitle = strcat('PC 2 (',num2str(weight(2)),'%)');
ylabel(ytitle, 'rotation', 42);
zlabel(ztitle);
%title('PCoA of colon samples');
xlabel('Days post DTH arthritis induction');
set(gca,'ZTick',-0.4:0.2:0.4)
set(gca,'ZTickLabel',{'','','','',''})
set(gca,'YTick',-0.5:0.2:0.3)
axis([1 3 -0.5 0.3 -0.4 0.4])
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'','','','',''})
set(gca,'XTick',1:3)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Day 0','Day 4','Day 9'})
set(gca,'fontsize',12,'fontname','Arial','fontweight', 'bold');
set(l,'fontsize',12,'fontname','Arial')
set(get(gca,'XLabel'),'FontSize',12,'fontname','Arial','fontweight', 'bold');
set(get(gca,'YLabel'),'FontSize',12,'fontname','Arial','fontweight', 'bold');
set(get(gca,'ZLabel'),'FontSize',12,'fontname','Arial','fontweight', 'bold');
h = rotate3d; 
set(h,'ActionPostCallback',@align_axislabels);


set(get(gca,'title'),'visible','off'); 
% 'FontSize',16, 'fontweight', 'bold');
set(gca,'ticklength',[0.0 0.0]);%style 6
set(gca,'tickdir','out');%style 7
grid on
hold off
view([18 30])
% print -r600 % set resolution
% saveas(figure(1),'PCoA1-2.tif') % save image as a .tiff file
```

Here is the data:

```
data =

    0.1866    0.0749   -0.1734       NaN         0
    0.2001    0.0151   -0.0393       NaN         0
    0.1057   -0.3854    0.0431       NaN         0
    0.2048    0.1505   -0.1489       NaN         0
    0.0482   -0.0006   -0.0153       NaN         0
    0.1343    0.2477    0.0639       NaN         0
    0.1886   -0.0139    0.1079       NaN         0
    0.1600   -0.0637   -0.1771       NaN    4.0000
    0.1571   -0.0156   -0.0961       NaN    4.0000
    0.1465   -0.1112   -0.0855       NaN    4.0000
    0.1758    0.0253   -0.1127       NaN    4.0000
    0.1655    0.0928   -0.1666       NaN    4.0000
    0.1491    0.0166    0.1677       NaN    4.0000
    0.1526    0.1451   -0.0703       NaN    4.0000
    0.1232   -0.3176   -0.0935       NaN    9.0000
    0.1360    0.1054   -0.1026       NaN    9.0000
    0.1938   -0.1332   -0.0826       NaN    9.0000
    0.2053   -0.1563    0.0799       NaN    9.0000
    0.1603    0.1803   -0.1093       NaN    9.0000
    0.1371    0.2595   -0.0826       NaN    9.0000
    0.1947   -0.1083   -0.0422       NaN    9.0000
    0.0839    0.0808    0.1522       NaN         0
    0.1757    0.0522    0.1423       NaN         0
   -0.3631    0.0319    0.0232       NaN         0
   -0.4284    0.0358   -0.0161       NaN         0
    0.0265    0.2092    0.2739       NaN         0
   -0.3970   -0.0270   -0.0618       NaN         0
   -0.3005   -0.1025   -0.0696       NaN         0
    0.1598    0.1318    0.0927       NaN    4.0000
    0.1753   -0.1845    0.1493       NaN    4.0000
   -0.2959   -0.0671   -0.1156       NaN    4.0000
   -0.4260    0.1470   -0.0722       NaN    4.0000
   -0.0407   -0.0009    0.0680       NaN    4.0000
   -0.2739   -0.1550    0.0370       NaN    4.0000
   -0.3063   -0.0713    0.0483       NaN    4.0000
    0.2129   -0.1394    0.1374       NaN    9.0000
    0.1940   -0.0936    0.0295       NaN    9.0000
   -0.3589    0.0083   -0.0007       NaN    9.0000
   -0.4232    0.0520    0.0296       NaN    9.0000
    0.0577    0.1052    0.2468       NaN    9.0000
   -0.3794   -0.0535    0.0540       NaN    9.0000
   -0.4176    0.0332   -0.0130       NaN    9.0000

weight =

   35.2300   11.4800    7.6900
```

Here is the graph produced by the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOtpu.jpg

I'd like the the lines of the DTR+ group to look similar to the DTR- group.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, try to post a MVCE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, meaning, we need to be able to copy paste the code and run it as it is. Also, being this a "visual" problem, is there the possibility of showing us what the desired result looks like?

Comment: also we need Matlab version number and figure render, respectivly the desired output format of the figure, if you want to save it.

Comment: Unfortunately, my reputation is below 10 and stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post pictures. Sorry.

Comment: @embacify just post a link to the image on drive or imgur or anything really and someone will add it to your question for you

Comment: @embacify, the link you posted is not accessible for everyone. You have to open the permission of your link.

Comment: I did manage to solve the problem my self, as stated in the answer. It was only a matter of perspective in the view window of Matlab and the saved image.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

Apparantly, the lines appearing different was an artifact produced by the specific viewing angle. When I manually rotated the graph in the view window, the lines appeared dashed as desired...

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the rapid responses...